# Firebase deploy doesn't find a function defined in a different file (other than index.js)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've created a function and it works to deploy it when it is in index.js but I've gone quite a few functions and the file kinda gets bigger. I've tried to move a function in a different file (e.g. get_data.js) but when I try to deploy the function I get the following error

```
The following functions are found in your project but do not exist in your local source code:
        getData(us-central1)
```

My project structure looks like this now:

```
node_modules/
index.js
get_data.js //this is where I've moved the function
...
```

```
package.json

{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "dateformat": "^4.6.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0",
    "node_extra_ca_certs_mozilla_bundle": "^1.0.5",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.7",
    "queryselector": "^0.1.0",
    "queryselectorall": "^0.1.0",
    "ssl-root-cas": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.9",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

and

```
get_data.js

exports.getAirQualityData = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 5 minutes").onRun(async (context) => { };
```

Any help in fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Cloud Functions must be exported from `index.js`. Try adding this in `index.js`:

```
/* Initialize Admin SDK */

export { getAirQualityData } from "./get_data.js"
```

This is also explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#write_functions_in_multiple_files).

Comment: didnt work (it says unexpected export)  but I've read the documentation (idk why I didnt think about it :/ ) and I found a solution

Comment: @t3nsa that was an example of ES6 syntax. Yours must be exports.getAirQualityData